# Spark : regression model threshold and precision

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

I have logistic regression mode, where I explicitly set the threshold to 0.5.

```
model.setThreshold(0.5)
```

I train the model and then I want to get basic stats -- precision, recall etc.

This is what I do when I evaluate the model:

```
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)

val precision = metrics.precisionByThreshold


precision.foreach { case (t, p) =>

      println(s"Threshold is: $t, Precision is: $p")

    }
```

I get results with only 0.0 and 1.0 as values of threshold and 0.5 is completely ignored.

Here is the output of the above loop:

Threshold is: 1.0, Precision is: 0.8571428571428571

Threshold is: 0.0, Precision is: 0.3005181347150259

When I call  metrics.thresholds() it also returns only two values, 0.0 and 1.0.

How do I get the precision and recall values with threshold as 0.5?

Answer (score 5):

You need to clear the model threshold before you make predictions. Clearing threshold makes your predictions return a score and not the classified label. If not you will only have two thresholds, i.e. your labels 0.0 and 1.0.

```
model.clearThreshold()
```

A tuple from predictionsAndLabels should look like `(0.6753421,1.0)` and not `(1.0,1.0)`

Take a look at https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/mllib/BinaryClassificationMetricsExample.scala

You probably still want to set numBins to control the number of points if the input is large.

Comment: please,I have predictionsAndLabels like (1.0,1.0) and precision and recall values for threshold 1,0 .I can't set threshold in pipeline model .how to solve this?                                                                                                                Threshold is: 0.0,recall is: 1.0                                                                                                                               Threshold is: 1.0,recall is: 1.0

Answer (score 1):

I think what happens is that all the predictions are 0.0 or 1.0. Then the intermediate threshold values make no difference.

Consider the `numBins` argument of `BinaryClassificationMetrics`:

> **`numBins`:**
>   if greater than 0, then the curves (ROC curve, PR curve) computed internally will be down-sampled to this many "bins". If 0, no down-sampling will occur. This is useful because the curve contains a point for each distinct score in the input, and this could be as large as the input itself -- millions of points or more, when thousands may be entirely sufficient to summarize the curve. After down-sampling, the curves will instead be made of approximately numBins points instead. Points are made from bins of equal numbers of consecutive points. The size of each bin is floor(scoreAndLabels.count() / numBins), which means the resulting number of bins may not exactly equal numBins. The last bin in each partition may be smaller as a result, meaning there may be an extra sample at partition boundaries.

So if you don't set `numBins`, then precision will be calculated at all the different prediction values. In your case this seems to be just 0.0 and 1.0.

Comment: Take a look at the contents of `predictionAndLabels` to confirm or disprove this theory!

Comment: I am still not sure about your comment. model.setThreshold(0.5) will make a score less than 0.5 in class 1 and > 0.5 to class 2. I have 2 classes. I am not sure how numbins will help with that.

Comment: If you don't set `numBins`, then precision will be calculated at all the different prediction values. In your case this seems to be just 0.0 and 1.0. I've added this to the answer. Take a look at the contents of `predictionAndLabels` to see if I'm right!

Comment: @DanielDarabos please,I have all values in prediction 1 or 0.  precision and recall values for threshold 1,0 .I can't set threshold in pipeline model .how to solve this? Threshold is: 0.0,recall is: 1.0 Threshold is: 1.0,recall is: 1.0.what's wrong?

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I haven't used this in ages. Post it as a new question an hopefully someone can give a useful answer! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

First, try adding more bins like this (here numBins is 10):

```
val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(probabilitiesAndLabels,10);
```

If you still only have two thresholds of 0 and 1, then check to make sure the way you have defined your predictionAndLabels. You many be having this problem if you have accidentally  provided `(label, prediction)` instead of `(prediction, label)`.