# Calculating Precision and Recall for specific threshold values

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to set  the threshold value of my logistic regression to 0.5 and I  want to get precision, recall, f1 score for this value for pipeline model .but

> model.setThreshold(0.5)

give me

> value setThreshold is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.ml.PipelineModel

```
    val Array(train, test) = dataset
      .randomSplit(Array(0.8, 0.2), seed = 1234L)
      .map(_.cache())
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
    .setInputCols(Array("label", "id", "features"))
    .setOutputCol("feature")
val pca = new PCA()
    .setInputCol("feature")
    .setK(2)
    .setOutputCol("pcaFeatures")
val classifier = new LogisticRegression()
    .setFeaturesCol("pcaFeatures")
    .setLabelCol("label")
 .setMaxIter(10).setRegParam(0.3).setElasticNetParam(0.8)
val pipeline = new Pipeline().setStages(Array(assembler, pca, classifier))
val model = pipeline.fit(train)
 val predicted = model.transform(test)
  predicted.show()
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.DenseVector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
val predictions = predicted.filter(row => row.getAs[Int]("label") == 1).map(row => (row.getAs[Int]("label"), row.getAs[DenseVector]  ("probability")(0)))
predictions.show()
import org.apache.spark.mllib.evaluation.MulticlassMetrics
val predictionAndLabels = predicted.
select($"label",$"prediction").
as[(Double, Double)].
rdd

val metrics = new BinaryClassificationMetrics(predictionAndLabels)

val precision = metrics.precisionByThreshold()
precision.foreach { case (t, p) =>
println(s"Threshold is: $t, Precision is: $p")
    }
    val recall = metrics.recallByThreshold
recall.foreach { case (t, p) =>
println(s"Threshold is: $t,recall is: $p")
}


+---+-------------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
| id|           features|label|             feature|         pcaFeatures|       rawPrediction|         probability|prediction|
+---+-------------------+-----+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+--------------------+----------+
|  3|0.03731932516607228|    1|[1.0,3.0,0.037319...|[-3.0000000581646...|[-0.8840273374633...|[0.29234391132806...|       1.0|
|  7| 0.9636476860201426|    1|[1.0,7.0,0.963647...|[-7.0000000960209...|[-0.8831455606697...|[0.29252636578097...|       1.0|
|  8| 0.4766320058073684|    0|[0.0,8.0,0.476632...|[-8.0000000194785...|[0.87801311177017...|[0.70641031990863...|       0.0|
| 45| 0.1474318959104205|    1|[1.0,45.0,0.14743...|[-45.000000062664...|[-0.8839183791391...|[0.29236645302163...|       1.0|
|103| 0.3443839885873453|    1|[1.0,103.0,0.3443...|[-103.00000007071...|[-0.8837251994055...|[0.29240642125330...|       1.0|
```

How to set threshold t value of my Logistic regression model with pipeline?

Comment: Can you put the code of the fit process?

Comment: yes,I update code in my question.@EmiCareOfCell44

Comment: @salmaz: You should use `setThreshold` on `classifier` in your code. Not `model` (which is a pipeline).

Comment: The code, with some changes in the names duplicated names, compiles

Comment: @EmiCareOfCell44  threshold 0,1 only appear "Threshold is: 1.0, Precision is: 1.0" "Threshold is: 0.0, Precision is: 0.50" I can't get values in threshold equal 0.5

Comment: @Shaido-ReinstateMonica  . I add setThreshold(0.5) in logistic Regression model but there isn't appear.

Comment: @salmaz: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34622728/mllib-calculating-precision-and-recall-for-multiple-threshold-values and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34216481/spark-regression-model-threshold-and-precision/36063766#36063766. Try not setting a threshold if you want to use `precisionByThreshold` / `recallByThreshold`.

Comment: thanks for your response.